# How do I setup multiple ChangeNotifierProvider of the same ChangeNotifier?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a class that extends `ChangeNotifier`, like this:

```
class NovelNotifier extends BaseNotifier {
  List<Novel> novels = [];
  Future<void> addListNovelByCategoryID({
    @required String id,
    int page = 1,
    int sort = 0,
    int status = 0,
    int totalChapter = 0,
  }) async {
    busy(true);
    final items = await _getListNovelFilter(
      id: id,
      url: urlGetNovelsFilter,
      page: page,
      sort: sort,
      status: status,
      totalChapter: totalChapter,
    );
    novels.addAll(items);
    busy(false);
  }
}
```

`addListNovelByCategoryID` will call Backend API based on `id` param, which represent category id. And I have like 14 categories, so I need 14 separated lists which has its own data and put them in `TabBarView`.

I planed to setup multiple `ChangeNotifierProvider<NovelNotifier>` but don't know how or whether `Provider` supports this case or not.

Comment: You cannot have multiple providers of the same type. See https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider#can-i-obtain-two-different-providers-using-the-same-type

Comment: This is really weird, bcs I've tried to deal the issue with below approach

Comment: @RémiRousselet can you take a look at the code below and give me some advice?